# ::after with position:relative not rendering correctly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-selectors, pseudo-element

When pseudo-element `tr::after` has `position: relative`, and the main element `tr` has `position: absolute`, that pseudo-element is positioned incorrectly on Safari.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make it work on Safari?

```css
tr {
  position: relative;
}

tr::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1-1 cell</td>
      <td>1-2 cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-1 cell</td>
      <td>2-2 cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3-1 cell</td>
      <td>3-2 cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Chrome

[image]

#### Safari

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is better to wrap the text in a "span", and already create an element for it

```
span::after{}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not it. I need to style the row, not the table cells for other reasons.
To explain further, I will be using this selector as `tr:not(:last-child)::after`